# Erro ao conectar em messageria Java JMS com activemq

Tags: java, jms

Estou criando um chat rudimentar para um trabalho da universidade, usando JMS e ActiveMQ

Está me dando esse erro que até então não consegui entender qual erro é esse e o porque dele
*`javax.jms.JMSException: Channel was inactive for too long: localhost/127.0.0.1:8161`*

Posso estar fazendo bobagem, mas segue a implementação do meu tópico e as filas.

```
private void topicos(){
        Context context = initContext();
        TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
        Topic topic = null;
        try{
            connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            topic = (Topic) context.lookup("Topic");
        }catch(NamingException nex){
            alertDialog("Impossível se conectar!" );
            alertDialog("Exceção gerada: " + nex);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        TopicConnection connection = null; //Criando a conexão e a sessão
        try{
            connection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
            TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.createSubscriber(topic);
            subscriber.setMessageListener(new Mensagens());
            connection.start();
        }catch(JMSException jex){
            alertDialog("Impossível de se conectar");
            System.out.println("Exceção gerada" + jex);
        }
    }


private void filas(){

        Context context = initContext();       

        QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;  // Cconexões da fábrica e da fila de destino
        Queue queue = null;
        try {
            connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");//pesquisa conexão
            queue = (Queue) context.lookup("Queue");//pesquisa o serviço
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        QueueConnection connection = null;
        try {// Criando a conexão e da sessão
            connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();

            //false => não utiliza transação)
            QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            String codigoUsuario = "KEY='" + usuario + "'";

            QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(queue, codigoUsuario); //passa a fila e a "senha" - nome do usuario        

            receiver.setMessageListener(new Mensagens());
            connection.start();

        } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```